# How to do unsigned 32 bit arithmetic in Perl?

Tags: perl, 32-bit, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I would like to implement the following C program in Perl:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t xorshift32 ()
{
  static uint32_t y = 2463534242;
  y ^= y << 13;
  y ^= y >> 17;
  y ^= y << 5;
  return y;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n = 10;
  while (n-- > 0)
    printf ("%u\n", xorshift32());
}
```

The output is:

```
723471715
2497366906
2064144800
2008045182
3532304609
374114282
1350636274
691148861
746858951
2653896249
```

This is my unsuccessful attempt:

```perl
{
  package Xorshift;
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use integer;

  sub new
  {
    my $class = shift;
    bless { y => 2463534242 } => $class
  }

  sub rand ()
  {
    my $y = $_[0]->{y};
    $y ^= $y << 13;
    $y ^= $y >> 17;
    $y ^= $y << 5;
    $_[0]->{y} = $y;
    return $y;
  }
}

my $xor = Xorshift->new;

my $n = 10;
while ($n-- > 0) {
  print $xor->rand(), "\n";
}
```

The output is this:

```
660888219700579
3396719463693796860
-1120433007023638100
2588568168682748299
1469630995924843144
-8422345229424035168
1449080611344244726
-4722527344582589597
8061824971057606814
-3113862584906767882
```

The problems:

1. Perl uses 64 bit arithmetic.
2. The integers are signed.

How to do 32 bit unsigned arithmetic instead?

Comment: Re "*Perl uses 64 bit arithmetic.*", Depends on the build

Comment: Re "*The integers are signed.*", No. `perl -E"$x = 2**62; $x <<= 1; say $x"` gives `9223372036854775808`. Remove, `use integer;` and you won't have that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simulate the result of 32-bit ops, you can simply apply a mask:

```
{
  package Xorshift;
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use integer;

  sub new
  {
    my $class = shift;
    bless { y => 2463534242 } => $class
  }
  
  sub to32{
    return ($_[0] & 0xFFFFFFFF);
  }

  sub rand ()
  {
    my $y = $_[0]->{y};
    $y ^= to32($y << 13);
    $y ^= to32($y >> 17);
    $y ^= to32($y << 5);
    $_[0]->{y} = $y;
    return $y;
  }
}

my $xor = Xorshift->new;

my $n = 10;
while ($n-- > 0) {
  print $xor->rand(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: This seems to work on a 64 bit system. But masking the left shift is sufficient? Without an additional function call it runs twice as fast.

Comment: @ceving, Sub calls are slow. Just inline it.

Comment: Both left and right shifts are masked with `to32`. As @ikegami said, you can of course inline the mask. To be consistent with your C code, you should also mask the original definition of `$y` in the package, but it will not be necessary unless you set too large a number.